# javascript variable is undefined in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

My global variable 'data' gets a messsage:

```
 [undefined × 4]
```

In the console log. That should be wrong as I've pushed 4 elements onto the array. This is the code

```
var data = [];

         ws.onmessage = function(evt){

         var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
         console.log(distances);
            for(var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
                if(buffer[i][0] == distances.miles) {
                    buffer[i][1][0]++;
                    }
            }               
            console.log(buffer);

            for (var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) { 
                data.push(buffer[i][1][0]); 
            }
            console.log(data);
            draw();//redraw the graph
            data.length=0;
        }
```

As you can see data should now be an array with elements.

Thanks

Comment: buffer[i][1][0] must be undefined, where is buffer initialised?

Comment: Buffer is initialised as a global:  var buffer = [['1',[0]],['2',[0]],['3',[0]],['4',[0]]];

Comment: if you log buffer[i][1][0], in the loop where you push it into data, what is it's value?

Comment: Could you tell me what distances.miles is? it would have to be a string (not int) like '1','2','3' or '4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console it's a live representation of the variables in memory, and you're invalidating the array's contents with `data.length=0;`. You should try something like `console.log($.clone(data));` (from jQuery) before `data.length=0;`.

This is assuming that you're absolutely sure that the data you expect really exists.

Comment: Good. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined` ... i have a problem json is bug =(